# Javac cannot find jar for apache commons config

Tags: java, linux, command-line, compilation

I'm trying to compile a very simple program in Java 1.6 on Ubuntu Jaunty, using Apache Commons Config jar.  I keep getting the "package org.apache.commons.configuration does not exist" error, even though the jar is in the same directory.  Any ideas?

- Directory Listing

```
~/source/UpdateStockHistory$ ll
total 304
-rw-r--r-- 1 crosse crosse 298829 2009-06-07 17:36 commons-configuration-1.6.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 crosse crosse    149 2009-06-07 17:16 UpdateStockHistory.config.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 crosse crosse    531 2009-06-07 17:46 UpdateStockHistory.java
```

- Java Version

```
~/source/UpdateStockHistory$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_13
```

- OS Version

```
~/source/UpdateStockHistory$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 9.04
Release:        9.04
Codename:       jaunty
```

- Compiler Version

```
~/source/UpdateStockHistory$ javac UpdateStockHistory.java
UpdateStockHistory.java:2: package org.apache.commons.configuration does not exist
import org.apache.commons.configuration.*;
^
UpdateStockHistory.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ConfigurationFactory
location: class com.crosse.tradingresearch.UpdateStockHistory
                        ConfigurationFactory factory = new ConfigurationFactory("UpdateStockHistory.config.xml");
                        ^
UpdateStockHistory.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ConfigurationFactory
location: class com.crosse.tradingresearch.UpdateStockHistory
                        ConfigurationFactory factory = new ConfigurationFactory("UpdateStockHistory.config.xml");
                                                           ^
UpdateStockHistory.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Configuration
location: class com.crosse.tradingresearch.UpdateStockHistory
                        Configuration config = factory.getConfiguration();
                        ^
4 errors
```

Hate to ask such a "do it for me" question, but I've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the jar to your classpath as so:

```
javac UpdateStockHistory.java -cp commons-configuration-1.6.jar
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I didn't realize I needed to add individual jars to my classpath.

Comment: Wow, back when I was relearning the classpath.  Thanks for all the help back then.

Answer (score 2):

Javac does not automatically search in the current directory for classes.  You can tell it to using:

```
javac -cp . UpdateStockHistory.java
```